# Is there a way to get my custom properties to show up in eclipse intellisense

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-custom-view, custom-properties

I have a custom View and it has a bunch of custom attributes that I pull in from the layout xml. However, unlike the properties that follow `android:` for which Eclipse offers me all the available options (and their possible values) my custom properties offer no help, so, I need to know what they are to use them.

I'm curious if there's some feature whereby I inform Eclipse about my namespace so that it knows where to go looking for the information (is this a custom DTD?) or if there's just no way to get this into the mix.

Comment: @danny117, what does that mean?

Comment: I was thinking of java not the xml files that views are made of.